# How can i make a flat object by removing keys in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I am really not sure if this could be achievable, How can i remove some nested keys in an Object and make the object very flat. I have a dynamic object as follows,

> EventData": {   "ChangeSet": {    "Change": {
>       "changes": [
>        ]    }  } }

and i want to change the above to

> EventData": { [] }

is this can be achieved in C#?

Comment: This looks more like json than c#

Comment: that is the dynamic Object i have, there is no way to post Object. so i have posted as JSON

Comment: You are probably using `dynamic` inappropriately and causing your self subsequent problems like this one. Is there a reason why you are using `dynamic`?

Comment: what do you mean by inappropriately? no this is the data stored on documentdb. i need to make a valid Object by removing unwanted fields

Comment: Where does this "object" come from?

Comment: @TheGeneral It comes from the database

Comment: i see, so its json?

Comment: I would suggest NewtonJson, deserialize the way you want to, then serialize again when you need to to store to DB.

Comment: yeah thats what i am doing now. so when i deserialize the extra keys are there. how can i do that?

Comment: @Aldert can you post an answer

Comment: @TheGeneral yes how can i deserialize and remove the unwanted suff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NewtonSoft.JSon package.. Following code does the trick. I made it a string array because I do not know what you need but you can change this to your liking.

```
const string complex = "{\"EventData\": { \"ChangeSet\": { \"Change\": { \"changes\" : [ ]}}}}";
```

Call to method:

```
string simple = returnSimpleObject(complex);


        public class SerializeData
        {
             public string[] EventData { get; set; }
        }

        private static string returnSimpleObject(string Json)
        {
            JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(Json);

            JToken tEventData = jobject.SelectToken("EventData");
            SerializeData myEvent = tEventData.ToObject<SerializeData>();

            JToken tchanges = jobject.SelectToken("EventData.ChangeSet.Change.changes");
            myEvent.EventData = tchanges.ToObject<string[]>();


            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            StringWriter strWrite = new StringWriter();
            JsonWriter myWriter = new JsonTextWriter(strWrite);
            serializer.Serialize(myWriter, myEvent);
            return strWrite.ToString();

        }
```